# python Fetch existing variables into a list

Tags: python, variables, local-variables, locals

I've used `locals()` function and created some variables. Now I need to fetch all the variables created into a list, how should I do?

example:

```
column_list=[x for x in range(100)]

for i,j in enumerate(column_list):
    locals()['v'+str(i)]=pd.DataFrame(['Y','N'],columns=[j])
```

Now, I have variables, v0 ~ v99, each of which is an independent data frame.

I need to fetch all the variables into a `variable_list`

So I can use for loop on all the variables:

```
variable_list -> [v0,v1,v2,v3,v4.v5.......]
```

Comment: Don't do that...  Use a dict.

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Answer (score 1):

Level up the abstraction.  Writing to [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) is not reliable, and is advised against in the documentation.

You should change the code where it creates sequential local variables named `v0`, `v1`, ... `v99` so that appends into one list named `v` in the first place.

Now, your "variable_list" is just `v` itself and the values in the list are accessible `v[0]`, `v[1]`, ... `v[99]`.

Comment: Yea, that worked.. But I still interested in knowing how to fetch existing variables anyway